# BigQuery NULL record evaluating against string condition in where clause incorrectly

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

DB: BigQuery

So I have a simple query that evaluates a string hash id against a condition in the where clause and it erroneously filters out one of my test records.

```
SELECT hash_id 
    FROM table
WHERE
    hash_id NOT IN (SELECT random_ids FROM another_table)
```

The null test record is excluded, even though the "another_table" in this example doesn't include any null records in the table whatsoever. I can only conclude that this returns a false condition which filters out the test record.

I have another where the where clause also fails against distinct conditions:

```
SELECT hash_id 
    FROM table
WHERE
    hash_id NOT IN ('123-abc', '456-def', '789-ghslkjhkjh')
```

This also omits the test null record, and I suspect it's for the same reasons. I'm not sure how to filter these out without resorting to placing the conditions in the join parameters?

Comment: In SQL `NULL` is ***neither equal nor not equal*** to any other value, including another `NULL`.  Try `WHERE hash_id IS NOT NULL  AND hash_id NOT IN (...)`.

Comment: So if I do IS NOT NULL, I'm filtering out records I want

Comment: Then `IS NULL OR ...` Either NULL or not on your list.

Comment: Can you show/illustrate (with sample data) the output of your sample queries above and also show/illustrate your expected output? This is to better visualize what your current scenario is versus your expected output.